# How to fix broker may not be available after broken pipe

Tags: apache-kafka

i connect to server through ssh, i launch my zookeper kafka, and my debezium connector, after a while only the kafka terminal tab get's kicked out with the following error 
`packet_write_wait: Connection to **.**.***.*** port 22: Broken pipe`

and my connector output is:

```
>>>>[2019-07-10 10:04:49,563] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] >>>>Connection to node 0 (ip-***.**.**.***.eu-
>>>>west-3.compute.internal/***.**.**.***:9092) could not be established. 
>>>>Broker may not be available. 
>>>>(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:725)

>>>>[2019-07-10 10:04:49,676] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongodb-source-
>>>>connector-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to 
>>>>flush outstanding 8 messages 
>>>>(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:420)

>>>>[2019-07-10 10:04:49,676] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongodb-source-
>>>>connector-0} Failed to commit offsets 
>>>>(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:111)
```

i don't want to restart manually everytime that happends, how can i fix this so i can only ssh one time launch the servers and connector then exit?.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Start the processes as a service ([ref](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/scripted-install.html))
2. Use a tool such as screen or tmux so that the session persists even after you close the connection.

Option (1) is how you do it in production. Option (2) is really handy for when you're in development, using VPNs, disconnecting/reconnecting etc — because not only does the process keep running, but you can also reconnect to your session as it was when you disconnected. Here's an example of what it is and how to use it: https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2012/05/screen-and-obiee/

Answer (score 0):

Alright so what i  did was
 sudo systemctl enable confluent-zookeeper
sudo systemctl enable confluent-kafka
sudo systemctl start confluent-zookeeper
i got a acces to file error, i've chmod it and now zookeeper works fine.
sudo systemctl start confluent-kafka
i got a error still couldn't fix , this is the output

```
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.j
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.openChannel(FileRecords.java:4
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.open(FileRecords.java:410)
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.open(FileRecords.java:419)
```